# What are the ways to pass the payload in stateless microservices?

Tags: microservices, payload, orchestration

I am working on several stateless microservices. I would like to know how I can pass the data between these microservices

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to communicate two services, you must define some things, the communication pattern you will use (directly point to point, broadcast using a message broker..), the way data will be serialized (how the information is coded to be transmitted, json, xml, binary... )and if the communication will be synchronous or asynchronous (if the transmitter have to wait to get a response or not).

These variables depend greatly on the use case you have to implement. If you don't have any requirement about scalability or performance and a point to point synchronous communication is enough, the simplest and most used way is that the service that will be called expose a REST API and the other call it serializing the message in the body of the request in json format.

As I don't know exactly the language or stack you are using. This is a tutorial to build a REST API using Spring and Java

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/